# Perl, How do I create a map/grep like subroutine?

Tags: perl, arguments

I want to create a subroutine like `grep {} @` or `map {} @` that can handle code and/or boolean input. Somehow the internet doesn't have much info on this.

I tried to create the sub below, but it can't even handle the first test. I get the error `Can't locate object method "BoolTest" via package "input" (perhaps you forgot to load "input"?) at C:\path\to\file.pl line 16.`.

How does this think it's an object? Am I not creating BoolTest correctly?

```
# Example senarios
BoolTest { 'input' =~ /test[ ]string/xi };
BoolTest { $_ =~ /test[ ]string/xi } @array;
BoolTest(TRUE);

# Example subroutine
sub BoolTest
{
   if ( ref($_[0]) == 'CODE') {
       my $code = \&{shift @_}; # ensure we have something like CODE
       if ($code->()) { say 'TRUE'; } else { say 'FALSE'; }
   } else {
       if ($_[0]) { say 'TRUE'; } else { say 'FALSE'; }
   }
}
```

Comment: `my $code = \&{shift @_};` is a complicated way of doing `my $code = shift;` (The reference (`\ `) and the dereference (`&{...}`) cancel out.)

Comment: @ikegami According to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6101734/127465, it is not entirely futile to use `\&{ ... }` as it ensures that the thing in braces can actually be coerced to a CODE ref.

Comment: @ThomasH, That's an awful way of doing that, and it's completely unnecessary. It's an awful way of checking if a something can be a sub ref because it can actually create an undefined sub in the process! And it's useless since the `$code->()` on the next line will also die in the same circumstances as `\&{ shift }` would.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To pass a code reference, you can use the following:

```
sub BoolTest { ... }

BoolTest sub { 'input' =~ /test[ ]string/xi };
BoolTest sub { $_ =~ /test[ ]string/xi }, @array;
BoolTest(TRUE);
```

You could have the sub have a similar syntax to `map BLOCK LIST`, by using the `&@` prototype.

```
sub BoolTest(&@) { ... }

BoolTest { 'input' =~ /test[ ]string/xi };
BoolTest { $_ =~ /test[ ]string/xi } @array;
```

This creates the same anonymous subs are earlier, so `return`, `last`, etc will behave the same as in the first snippet.

Note that the prototyped version won't accept

```
BoolTest(TRUE);
```

unless you override the prototype

```
&BoolTest(TRUE);
```

But you shouldn't expect your caller to do that. Based on your example, you could have them use the following, but a second sub might be better.

```
BoolTest { TRUE };
```

Comment: Can I do `BoolTest {}` without the prototypes? I heard protos are bad practice.

Comment: It's a bad practice to use prototypes *to validate arguments* because prototypes change parsing rules. In this case, you actually want to change the parsing rules, so all's good.

Comment: This is one of the cases when you really should use prototypes.

Comment: Now I get `Use of uninitialized value $_` for the `{ $_ == 1 }` example. Isn't the code suppose to go in unexecuted?

Comment: Your code never sets `$_`. Presumably you want to set it to each of the remaining values of `@_` (which can be done using `for (@_) { $code->() }`).