# Perl: Abstraction of function taking block of code as an argument

Tags: perl

For my testing, I wanted to add a function that could time a block of code. The block of code would be like map where you give it in braces. I used this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6101734/11365539) and it works well.

Timer.pm

```perl
sub recordTime(&@)
{
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/6101734/11365539
    my $code = \&{shift @_};
    my %opts = @_;

    $opts{name}  //= 'Time';
    $opts{fmt}   //= 'default';
    $opts{hires} //= 0;

    my $timing_sub = $opts{hires} ? \&CORE::time : \&Time::HiRes::time;

    my $start = $timing_sub->();
    $code->();
    my $end = $timing_sub->();

    my $output;
    if($opts{log})
    {
        $output = IO::File->new($opts{log}, '>>')
                    or carp("Failed to open $opts{log}. Outputting to STDOUT...");
    }
    if(not defined($output)) #if $opts{log} is undefined or IO::File->new() failed
    {
        $output = *STDOUT;
    }

    my $time_diff = $end - $start;
    $output->print("$opts{name}: ");

    # formatting time and printing it

    {
        no warnings 'numeric'; # perl complains that *STDOUT is not numeric
        if($output != *STDOUT)
        {
            $output->close();
        }
    }
}

1;
```

This code seems to work as expected. I can use it like this:

```perl
Timer::recordTime {
    runTests();
} (name => 'Run all tests', log => $timing_log);
```

I don't want to write `log => $timing_log` everywhere, so I added this function in another module.

TesterInterface.pm

```perl
sub logTime(&@)
{
    my $code = \&{shift @_};
    my %opts = @_;

    Timer::recordTime {
        $code->();
    } (%opts, log => $timing_log);
}
```

So I would use it like this

```perl
TesterInterface::logTime {
    runTests();
} (name => "Run all tests");
```

This keeps throwing absurd errors such as `Undefined subroutine &main::0 called`. To me it seems like this is evaluating an implicit return of the last line of `$code`. I tested this by adding a `say("hi")` statement at the end of the code block which will return 1. I then saw `Undefined subroutine &main::1 called`. I tried to then escape it by changing the line to `\ say("hi")`, but that produces this error: `Can't call method "logTime" on unblessed reference`. I really have no idea how to fix this.

I did find that doing this will work, but I would prefer to avoid having to write `sub`. I also don't understand why this method works, but not the code block version.

```perl
TesterInterface::logTime(sub {
    runTests();
}, name => 'Run all tests');
```

I'm using Perl v5.22.1 in Windows

Comment: `my $code = shift;`?

Comment: Perhaps this is related to the [indirect object notation, which frequently causes problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32955172/what-is-indirect-object-notation-why-is-it-bad-and-how-does-one-avoid-it)

Answer (score 2):

You have not provided a demonstration of the problem, but it's apparent the call to `Timer::recordTime` occured was compiled before `Timer::recordTime`'s declaration was compiled.

This causes

```perl
Timer::recordTime { $code->(); } ( %opts, log => $timing_log );
```

to be parsed as an indirect method call equivalent to the following:

```perl
do { $code->(); }->Timer::recordTime( %opts, log => $timing_log );
```

---

By the way,

```perl
my $code = \&{shift @_};
```

is a complicated way of doing

```perl
my $code = shift;
```

The former does accept a sub name in addition to a sub ref, but the prototype doesn't allow that.

---

By the way, your `logTime` adds a lot of unnecessary overhead. I'd use:

```perl
sub logTime(&@) {
   &Timer::recordTime( @_, log => $timing_log );
}
```

The `&` causes the prototype to be ignored.

Comment: Throwing in a `no indirect;` at the top may verify ikegami's suspicion. This would disallow that surprise. If you are on the latest perl, a `use v5.36;` gives you that for free.

Comment: @brian d foy `use v5.36;` will cause problems in this situation as it enable sub sigs

Comment: I updated the question. Got a little messed up in trying to simplify my use case. Let me know if you need more info. Do you need to know how the modules are being included in the files? I did update my code to use your version with less overhead

Comment: Re "*I updated the question.*", None of the changes affects the answer. /// Re "*Let me know if you need more info.*", I don't need any more info. I already identified the problem.

Comment: I assume you mean how it's compiling before seeing the prototype. Can I do something about that? I include my module at the top of the file

Comment: Do the modules load each other (directly or otherwise)?

Comment: `TesterInterface.pm` loads `Timer.pm` and `Tester1.pm`. `Tester1.pm` which uses `logTime` loads `TesterInterface.pm`. This is with `use`.

Comment: TesterInterface.pm loads Tester1.pm, and Tester1.pm loads TesterInterface.pm. Therein lies the problem. One of the `use` effectively becomes a no-op. Avoid this.